# How to start a runnable after another finishes?

Tags: spring, runnable

Iam using Spring  3.9.4 and I am using two Runnables. the first one populates a map (in the class scope ) and the second one needs to use the map for further processing-. The problem here is the first runnable should complete before the second one starts.How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I doubt you are using Spring 3.9.4 because there is no such version. What have you tried, post that here. Hint, use `Future` and chain them.

Comment: Sorry I meant STS 3.9.4. Can you please give an example with Future

Comment: Look at this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)